# CSSTransition from react-transition-group not applying classes

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, css-modules, react-transition-group, reactcsstransitiongroup

I'm trying to integrate CSSTransition to my Gatsby site, but it is not applying any of the classes. I'm utilizing CSS modules, and I've got a `<div>` that serves as the parent that fades in and out, essentially applying the fade effect to this and covering the content while it changes. It's got the class `fadEffect`. Here is my `app-layout` component, and the SASS.

**AppLayout.tsx**

```
import React, { ReactNode, useState } from 'react';

import { ApiContext } from 'contexts/ApiContext';
import { graphql, StaticQuery } from 'gatsby';
import { TransitionGroup, CSSTransition } from 'react-transition-group';

import { Devtools } from '../devtools/Devtools';
import { Footer } from '../footer/Footer';
import { Header } from '../header/Header';
import s from './AppLayout.scss';

interface AppLayoutProps {
  children: ReactNode;
  location: string;
}

const isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development';

// tslint:disable no-default-export
export default ({ children, location }: AppLayoutProps) => {
  const [fadeEffectVisible, setFadeEffectVisible] = useState(false);

  const handleFadeEffectEntered = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setFadeEffectVisible(false);
    }, 50);
  };

  return (
    <StaticQuery
      query={`${NavQuery}`}
      render={(data) => (
        <>
          <ApiContext>
            <Header navigationContent={data.prismic.allNavigations.edges[0].node} />

            <CSSTransition
              in={fadeEffectVisible}
              timeout={150}
              classNames={{
                enter: s.fadeEffectEnter,
                enterActive: s.fadeEffectEnterActive,
                enterDone: s.fadeEffectEnterDone,
                exit: s.fadeEffectExit,
                exitActive: s.fadeEffectExitActive,
              }}
              onEntered={handleFadeEffectEntered}
            >
              <div className={s.fadeEffect} aria-hidden="true" />
            </CSSTransition>

            <TransitionGroup component={null}>
              <CSSTransition
                key={location}
                timeout={150}
                classNames={{
                  enter: s.pageEnter,
                }}
              >
                <div className={s.layout}>
                  {children}

                  <Footer navigationItems={data.prismic.allNavigations.edges[0].node} />

                  {isDev && <Devtools />}
                </div>
              </CSSTransition>
            </TransitionGroup>
          </ApiContext>
        </>
      )}
    />
  );
};

const NavQuery = graphql`
  query NavQuery {
    prismic {
      allNavigations {
        edges {
          node {
            ...NotificationBar
            ...NavigationItems
            ...FooterNavigationItems
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

**AppLayout.scss**

```
@import '~styles/config';

:global {
  @import '~styles/base';
}

.layout {
  display: block;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.pageEnter {
  display: none;
}

.fadeEffect {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  transition: opacity 0.15s linear;

  &Enter {
    display: block;
    opacity: 0;
  }

  &Active,
  &Done,
  &Exit {
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
  }

  &ExitActive {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

I'm happy to provide more details/code if this isn't enough. I'm newish to React and Gatsby, so I'm still learning the lingo. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have added my suggestion as an answer if that still doesn't work, could you please share codesandbox link with issue reproduced?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see part of your code where you are updating `fadeEffectVisible` to true for first `CSSTransition` and I don't see `in` property at all on second `CSSTransition` and I would bet that is your issue. Please take a look at this example from [React Transition Group](http://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/css-transition) for understanding usage of properties.

**App.js**

```
function App() {
  const [inProp, setInProp] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div>
      <CSSTransition in={inProp} timeout={200} classNames="my-node">
        <div>
          {"I'll receive my-node-* classes"}
        </div>
      </CSSTransition>
      <button type="button" onClick={() => setInProp(true)}>
        Click to Enter
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Style.css**

```
.my-node-enter {
  opacity: 0;
}
.my-node-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 200ms;
}
.my-node-exit {
  opacity: 1;
}
.my-node-exit-active {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 200ms;
}
```

When the `in` prop is set to true, the child component will first receive the class `example-enter`, then the `example-enter-active` will be added in the next tick.

Comment: Thanks for this, after some digging it seems like it's an issue with `fadeEffectVisible` always returning false. That being said, I'm not sure exactly how to change the state to `true`. Any suggestions, given my code above?

Comment: @JesseWinton you can use any even handler for example use click or even in constructor you can set default stat to true.